# Local Database Update Existing Record - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am having trouble to update data from my local database. This is my code:

```
private void appBarOkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string selectedRowOrderId = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedRowOrderId))
        {
            int selectedID = int.Parse(selectedRowOrderId);
            var query = from TblCustomers customer in orderDB.Customers
                        where customer.Id == selectedID
                        select customer;

           TblCustomers editCustomer = query.FirstOrDefault();
            if (editCustomer != null)
                editCustomer.Name = txtBoxCustomerName.Text;

                App.ViewModel.SaveChangesToDB();



                 // Return to the main page.
                if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
                {
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                }
            }
    }
```

And this is the model side:

```
public void SaveChangesToDB()
    {
        orderDB.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

When I try to change something in Database, Everythings look OK while debugging. But nothing is changing at the end. Could you help me please.

Comment: Did you follow a guide when creating your db layer? could add details about the data layer?

Comment: I used Microsoft Samples for Local Database. My database is working properly. I can add and remove. But couldn`t figure out to edit data :(

Comment: Please post the url to the samples you are following so i may help you debug/fix your project

Comment: I started to develop by using this sample:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Did you make any changes in the app.xaml.cs where the ViewModel is being initialized?

Comment: Nope mate, Nothing is changed in app.xaml.cs. If you tell me how can I edit a task in the sample, it would be very helpful. It is very funny that microsoft didnt put data uptade to its sample :S

Comment: :D i'm trying to replicate the sample or download right now

Comment: What does it mean that it doesn't change at the end?

Comment: Nothing changes in database.

Comment: To me it's working maybe you didn't implement all the requirements in the model

Comment: Are you able to change existing data in DB ? Could you send me the code for editing? Because in that sample there is not a code for editing existing data.

Comment: In MVVM the editing is automatically done on the objects, on save the objects are saved to the database, so there is no Edit/Save process

Comment: In the example you have the IsCompleted witch value is changed and persisted

Comment: Ok mate. I didnt think the IsComplated field is an editing event. Now I will start thinking again. :) Thank you very much!

Comment: every property in there is editable. To be able to edit them without code in your Binding you should do Mode=TwoWay

Comment: I created a page for Editing ToDo items. When I change ToDo Items name and save it, It creates a new Item to the database. (Even I change the binding to Mode=TwoWay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Page

XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ToDoListBoxItemTemplate">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding ItemName,Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" 
                Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-36, 12, 0, 0"
                     ></TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <ListBox  
        x:Name="allToDoItemsListBox" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding AllToDoItems}" 
        Margin="12, 0, 12, 0" Width="440" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ToDoListBoxItemTemplate}" />
</Grid>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton 
            IconUri="/Images/appbar.check.rest.png" 
            Text="Save" 
            x:Name="newTaskAppBarButton" 
            Click="newTaskAppBarButton_Click"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class EditPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public EditPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        App.ViewModel.SaveChangesToDB();
    }

    private void newTaskAppBarButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
}
```

Works for me

Comment: You add new task, then open it again and you change its name with this code?

Comment: yes i change it from that view, the XAML pasted is only the content not the whole code of the view

Comment: There is something that I am missing. :(

Comment: for everyone`s attention: @verdesrobert is an expert :)